# Does this function belong to local Hardy space?

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the Hardy space on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here, we define a new function
$$
F=\begin{cases}
f&, x_n\ge 0\\
0&, x_n<0.
\end{cases}
$$

My question is as described in the title: Does this function belong to **local** Hardy space $\mathcal{h}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

We can write $F$ in an alternative way by using charateristic function $\chi$ as follows
$$
F=f\cdot\chi_{\{x_n\ge 0\}}
$$

I guess in general for $g\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n),f\in \mathcal{h}^1(\mathbb{R}^n),f\cdot g\not\in\mathcal{h}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But I am not sure whether $F\in \mathcal{h}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or not.